# How to Convert Date String 12012017 to DATE using SQL by format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server

Periode = 12012017

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(Periode,1,2) +'/'+SUBSTRING(Periode,3,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(Periode,5,4)) AS TheDate
```

How to obtain date with format like 13-01-2017 (dd/mm/yyyy)?

Comment: What do you get when you execute that query ? what is the datatype for `Periode`?

Comment: If you want a string representation in a specific format why are you casting it to `DATE` after the concatenation? Also `13-01-2017 ` is `dd-mm-yyyy` not `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: Firstly, since you don't specify a conversion style how `'12012017'` actually gets interpreted in your statement totally depends on your current `SET DATEFORMAT` setting and so it could result in either `2017-01-12` (DMY) or `2017-12-01` (MDY). Secondly, SQL Server stores dates, times and datetimes as binary values so they don't have a format, as such, that's purely a presentation function of SSMS or your preferred client software.

Answer (score 1):

There are really two approaches to this - either

- Just treat it as a simple 'text' editing (shifting characters around, adding slashes etc).
- Convert it to a date, then display the date as you want.

I much prefer the latter as it will at least ensure you have a date. If you do the first, it will often happily convert `abcdefgh` to `ab/cd/efgh`.

To convert it to a date, unless it is exactly in the format `yyyymmdd`, I usually use `DATEFROMPARTS` rather than creating a text string.

- It's really clear how each part is calculated - I find it simpler to read and therefore maintain.
- Depending on your localisation/region settings and how you create the text date, you can get it really wrong. So it's also safer/more reliable than relying on automatic conversions.

DATEFROMPARTS has 3 parameters - the year, the month, then the day. You can use the SUBSTRING functions you have in your question to do these.

The following code (also available at this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_xHNTb6c)) shows this first part - generating a true date record.

```
DECLARE @Periode nvarchar(10) = N'12012017';
DECLARE @Periode_date date;

SELECT @Periode_date = DATEFROMPARTS(SUBSTRING(@Periode,5,4), SUBSTRING(@Periode,3,2), SUBSTRING(@Periode,1,2));
SELECT @Periode_date;
```

The result for this is `2017-01-12` - the correct date, but not the correct format.

To format it, you can then convert it to the relevant format using the `CONVERT` function which allows you to specify the style as well (note that CAST cannot do this) - see [CAST and CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for reference.

For us, the format we want is 103, so we use this command

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @Periode_date, 103);
```

And the result is `12/01/2017`.

As a final note - I'd also put in error checking (e.g., a TRY CATCH block) to ensure errors are handled the way you want.